# "on" that isn't "on top of"

Tags: word-choice

Sorry if the title is bad, I didn't know how to put it.

Take the following sentence, "He flipped the pancake so vigorously it got stuck on the ceiling".
When we think about the word "on", we usually think of "on top of".

So is there a word that doesn't sound as weird that could be used in place?

Comment: "The show must go on!" "Let us march on!" "On to the next item on our agenda." are all examples of the word "on" not meaning "on top of."

Comment: The television is on.  The lights are on.  Why do you think this is wrong?  BTW - the on you are using in that sentence refers to on the surface of the ceiling.

Comment: "it got stuck on" is fine, as is "it stuck to"

Comment: He is on television. On the road again. There's nearly a limitless number of non-on-top-of uses of on. Why associate it with that?

Answer (score 2):

As pavja2 mentions in their comment, "on" does not always mean "on top of", so there is nothing inherently wrong with your original construct.

"to" would be a good alternative in that case, though, if you didn't like "on" for whatever reason.  Things are often stuck *to* other things.

Answer (score 0):

We flipped the pancake so hard it stuck to the ceiling.

Simpler, and the vigorous is a bit pedantic.

Answer (score -1):

You are right. 'On'primarily conveys the idea of support by two dimensional object and also one dimensional object - surface and line: Table top/road;river;coast;border etc. But that's not all. Anything adhering to a surface is expressed by ON. On the arm, leg, etc.

Comment: Welcome to English.se. How is this answering the question? Or rather when you say *You are right*, what does that mean?